# NPGSQL + dataGridView + change of dg in code

Tags: c#, datagridview, npgsql

I have one problem in my app. I am using NPGSQL library to connect to PostgreSQL server. Everything is ok. But :)

I am feeling dataGridView like this:

```
dataSetUzytkownicy = new DataSet("users");
dataAdapterUzytkownicy = new NpgsqlDataAdapter();
dataAdapterUzytkownicy.SelectCommand = new NpgsqlCommand("select * from users", bazaDanych.Connection);
dataAdapterUzytkownicy.Fill(dataSetUzytkownicy, "users");
dataTableUzytkownicy = dataSetUzytkownicy.Tables["users"];
dgUzytkownicy.DataSource = dataTableUzytkownicy;
```

next I call methods for insert, update and delete. It is working good. I have one more button. I need after click on it, change one value in row from true to false. I'm doing this in this code:

```
dgUzytkownicy.SelectedRows[0].Cells[5].Value = false;
dataAdapterUzytkownicy.Update(dataSetUzytkownicy, "users");
```

It changes value in dataGrid, but after I click save which is:

```
dataAdapterUzytkownicy.Update(dataSetUzytkownicy, "users");
```

it doesn't make change to DB. I think that this is simple thing, but I have no idea what to do.

Thx for answers.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is:

```
dataTableUzytkownicy.Rows[dgUzytkownicy.SelectedRows[0].Index][5] = false;
```